# How to apply function to all rows in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am confused about how to apply a function to a data frame. Generally with creating user-defined-functions, I am familiar with ultimately having a "return" value to produce. Except for this case, I need the "return" value to show up in every cell of a data frame column, and I can't figure this out. The function is based on "if" and "if else" conditional statements, and I am unsure how to apply this to my data frame. Maybe I am perhaps missing a parentheses or bracket somewhere, but I am not entirely sure. I will explain here below.

I have the following dataframe:

```
       Day      No_employee?       No_machinery?      Production_potential
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    Day 1                 1                   0                         5      
1    Day 2                 1                   1                         4
2    Day 3                 0                   1                         3
3    Day 4                 1                   0                         8
4    Day 5                 0                   0                         6
5    Day 6                 0                   1                         3
6    Day 7                 0                   0                         5
7    Day 8                 1                   1                         2
...
```

Now I want to take my dataframe and append a new column called `Production_lost`, based on the following logic:

In a factory, to manufacture products, you need both 1) an employee present, and 2) functioning machinery. If you cannot produce any product, then that potential product becomes lost product.

For each day (thinking about a factory), if `No_employee?` is true ( = 1), then no products can be made, regardless of `No_machinery?` and `Production_lost` = `Production_potential`. If `No_machinery?` is true ( = 1), then no products can be made, regardless of `No_employee?`, and `Production_lost` = `Production_potential`. Only if `No_employee?` and `No_machinery?` both = 0, will `Production_lost` = 0. If you have both an employee present and functioning machinery, there will be no production loss.

So I have the following code:

```
df['Production_loss'] = df['No_employee?'].apply(lambda x: df['Production_potential'] if x == 1.0 else df['Production_potential'] * df['No_machinery?'])
```

which produces the following error message:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 70, placement implies 1
```

I understand this means that there are too many arguments being applied to a single column (I think), but I am not sure how to address this, or how I might have reached this problem. Is there a simple fix to this?

The dataframe I am trying to produce would look like this:

```
       Day      No_employee?       No_machinery?      Production_potential     Production_lost
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0    Day 1                 1                   0                         5                   5
1    Day 2                 1                   1                         4                   4
2    Day 3                 0                   1                         3                   3  
3    Day 4                 1                   0                         8                   8
4    Day 5                 0                   0                         6                   0
5    Day 6                 0                   1                         3                   3
6    Day 7                 0                   0                         5                   0
7    Day 8                 1                   1                         2                   2
...
```

Comment: Has any of the answers solved your problem?

Comment: This problem has been solved, I went with the solution from It_is_Chris, since it matched what I already had most closely, but both are great suggestions, so thank you.

Comment: Glad that we could help. Can you thus mark @It_is_Chris answer as accepted? This way people with similar issues will find answers more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy.where

```
df['Production_lost'] = np.where(((df['No_employee?'] == 1) | (df['No_machinery?'] == 1)),
                                 df['Production_potential'], 0)

     Day  No_employee?  No_machinery?  Production_potential  Production_lost
0  Day 1             1              0                     5                5
1  Day 2             1              1                     4                4
2  Day 3             0              1                     3                3
3  Day 4             1              0                     8                8
4  Day 5             0              0                     6                0
5  Day 6             0              1                     3                3
6  Day 7             0              0                     5                0
7  Day 8             1              1                     2                2
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use apply, use [pd.Series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) instead:

```
df['Production_loss'] = df['Production_potential'].where(df['No_employee?'].eq(1), df['Production_potential'] * df['No_machinery?'])
```

You can also use multiplication:

```
df['Production_loss'] = ~(df['No_employee?'] * df['No_machinery?']) * df['Production_potential']
```